SQL Inner Join is incorrectly returning 'None' in an entire column
I am a hobbyist who is trying to deploy a Flask app with Heroku.  The project worked fine when running locally.  I was using SQLite locally and transferred the database to Postgres on Heroku.
I have two tables that I am working with.
layouts:  layout_id, class_id, layout_name, num_groups, etc.
classes:  class_id, user_id, classname, etc.

I am trying to get all the layouts tied to a particular user_id.
Here is my Python code:
id = session.get("user_id")
layouts = db.execute("SELECT * FROM layouts INNER JOIN classes ON classes.class_id = layouts.class_id WHERE classes.user_id = ?", (id,))

The code finds all the correct rows from the layouts table, but in every row the value of layout_id is 'None', even though that is not actually the case.  All the other columns have the correct data.
For example, when I just do a simple SELECT statement, I get:
[{'layout_id': 341, 'class_id': 54, 'layout_name': 'using order by', 'num_groups': 10, 'disp_first': 1, 'disp_nick': 0, 'disp_last': 1, 'disp_grade': 0, 'front_loc': 1}]

When I use the INNER JOIN above, this row shows up as:
{'layout_id': None, 'class_id': 54, 'layout_name': 'using order by', 'num_groups': 10, 'disp_first': 1, 'disp_nick': 0, 'disp_last': 1, 'disp_grade': 0, 'front_loc': 1, 'user_id': 5, 'classname': 'Heroku test class', 'period': '8'}

UPDATE:
As suggested by nbk, I stopped using SELECT *.  When I try
layouts = db.execute("SELECT layout_id, class_id, layout_name, num_groups, disp_first, disp_nick, disp_last, disp_grade, front_loc FROM layouts INNER JOIN classes ON classes.class_id = layouts.class_id WHERE classes.user_id = ?", (id,))

I get an error message saying:
psycopg2.errors.AmbiguousColumn: column reference "layout_id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT layout_id, class_id, layout_name, num_groups, disp_fi...

There are not two columns named "layout_id" so I do not know why this would be ambiguous.
I do not have a CREATE TABLE in my code.  Here is the code that creates the new row in layouts
db.execute("INSERT INTO layouts (class_id, layout_name, num_groups, disp_first, disp_nick, disp_last, disp_grade, front_loc) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", request.form.get("class_id"), request.form.get("layoutName"),10,1,0,1,0,1)

When I created the layouts table in SQLIte, layout_id was an auto increment integer, primary key.  class_id was a foreign key.  I have not been able to figure out how to inspect my Postgres database (which was converted from the SQLite database) in Heroku.  I know there is a lot of stuff out there about that process, but I haven't gotten anything to work yet.  I'm basically inspecting the database by running the SQL from within my project.
I have done research and have not been able to find a similar question.  As I mentioned, the project worked fine with this code locally using SQLite.  I can't think of anything to try because the INNER JOIN is finding the correct rows.
Hopefully this is enough information.  Thank you!

First don't use SELECT * second add create table with data as INSERT INTO  to your question and wanted result

Can you post the full table structure of both the tables from PostgreSQL database.

It turns out that there was a layout_id in another table.  Changing to "SELECT layouts.layout_id" seems to have fixed the problem.  Thank you!
